# Creating a class to connect to mongo in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, api

I'm creating a class to connect and query a mongo database for a Web REST Api in .Net Framework 4.8 Web Application. The API will run in Windows Server using IIS.

So I had a few doubts on what would better when connecting and query on mongo.From that i thought of 3 different ways to create this class.

My first doubt is if I should save the connection in a private variable and create functions  that only used this single connection or if should create a connection for every query?

My second doubt is, if i choose to save the connection in a private variable, is it better for class the be an instance class or static class?

What are the pro/cons of each way?

Is there any issue that might happen in any of them?

Am I doing a bad programming practice with any of these ways?

```
//Static class with private connection variable
public static class MongoTables
{
    private static IMongoCollection<object> collec;
    private static MongoClient client;
    public static void Connect(string connectionString)
    {
        client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        collec = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase").GetCollection<object>("MyCollection");
    }
    public static object GetFirst(string value)
    {
        return collec.AsQueryable<object>().First(t => t.Field1 == value);
    }
    public static List<object> GetList(string value)
    {
        return collec.AsQueryable<object>().Where(t => t.Field1 == value).ToList();
    }
}
//Static class with a connection for each query
public static class MongoTables
{
    
    public static object GetFirst(string value)
    {
        using(MongoClient client = new MongoClient("connectionString"))
            return client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase").GetCollection<object>("MyCollection").AsQueryable<object>().First(t => t.Field1 == value);
    }
    public static List<object> GetList(string value)
    {
        using(MongoClient client = new MongoClient("connectionString"))
            return client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase").GetCollection<object>("MyCollection").AsQueryable<object>().Where(t => t.Field1 == value).ToList();
    }
}
//Instance class with private connection variable
public class MongoTables
{
    private IMongoCollection<object> collec;
    private MongoClient client;
    
    public MongoTables(string connectionString)
    {
        client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        collec = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase").GetCollection<object>("MyCollection");
    }
    public object GetFirst(string value)
    {
        return collec.AsQueryable<object>().First(t => t.Field1 == value);
    }
    public List<object> GetList(string value)
    {
        return collec.AsQueryable<object>().Where(t => t.Field1 == value).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The context class, in your case it's `MongoTables` should have scoped or transient lifetime. Also you need use DI for `IMongoClient` with `Singleton` lifetime, and remove `Connect` from context class. In `Startup` class register your dependency like `services.AddSingleton<IMongoClint>(_ => new MongoClient("some connection string"))` and thats it)

Also, I recommend you to use filters instead of `IQueryable`